# "Item not found" error is returned when i try to get file details that has been shared by the external user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-2013, onedrive, shared-file, microsoft-graph-sites

Shared with me API provides me the list of all files and folders that are shared by internal and external users.
The Shared API URL is mentioned below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

But when I try to access the shared DriveItem resource of the file that has been shared by the external user bypassing DriveID and File ID into the API
/drives/{remoteItem-driveId}/items/{remoteItem-id}
The API throws an error as -

```
{
"error": {
"code": "itemNotFound",
"message": "Item not found",
"innerError": {
"date": "2020-10-20T12:07:39",
"request-id": "5a3b3836-fe3e-450a-837e-1b3e962ac94b",
"client-request-id": "5a3b3836-fe3e-450a-837e-1b3e962ac94b"
}
}
}
```

But the Same API works fine with the file shared with Internal Users.
Am I missing something here any help is greatly appreciated?

Regards,
Kuldeep K

Comment: For external tenants make sure you append `?allowexternal=true` according to the [public document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#remarks) and then give a try.

Comment: Moving this to Answer.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? I am seeing the same issue. (allowexternal does not help fetch the DriveItem).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to get workbook info from an excel made by a colleague. I was initially using

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{drive-item-id}/workbook/worksheets
```

and fixed it using:

```html
GET /drives/{remoteItem-driveId}/items/{remoteItem-id}/workbook/worksheets
```

The drive ID is under "parent reference" and in my case, the remote ID under "remoteItem" was the same as the first id listed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For external tenants make sure you append `?allowexternal=true` according to the [public document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#remarks) and then give a try.

Comment: Tried but still the same