# Microsoft Graph API Problem Accessing OneDrive Items Shared by External User

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant, onedrive

I am writing a .NET desktop app that uses the Microsoft Graph API to access the contents of my OneDrive for Business storage.  I am logging in to Graph using my Microsoft work/school account U1, in my organization O1.  Another Microsoft work/school account, U2, in a different organization, O2, has shared a folder with me.  The folder shows up in "Shared With You" when I browse my OneDrive interactively in a browser, and I can make changes to the folder there.  It also shows up as a DriveItem in the returned list when my app uses the "sharedWithMe" API call documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (with allowexternal set to true).

All good so far.  The problem is when I try to actually retrieve the shared folder using the returned DriveItem.  I am following the guidance in the doc page to use a call like

```
GET /drives/{remoteItem-driveId}/items/{remoteItem-id}
```

to retrieve the folder, and I have the "Files.ReadWrite.All" permission.  I believe I am doing this correctly in my code, because it works fine on other items shared with me by users in my organization.  However, with the folder shared by U2, this call fails with an "itemNotFound" error.  I don't understand why this fails.  Is this a problem with my code, or some configuration that needs to be done in my organization O1, or in their organization O2, or a combination?  Or is what I'm trying to do just not possible across organizations?

I have found a couple other folks who have had similar problems, but the resolutions are inconclusive: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64909544/item-not-found-error-is-returned-when-i-try-to-get-file-details-that-has-been), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/281362/graph-api-unable-to-access-an-external-file-shared.html), and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/283546/graph-api-how-to-access-a-shared-driveitem-from-an.html).  These links have suggested a couple directions:

- could this be a problem with some sharing setting on the part of organization O2?  Unfortunately I don't have any control over this org.  But if I can give them a clear request, preferably with some Microsoft docs to back it up, I think they would be receptive.  For example, does organization O2 need to add/invite my account U1 as an external/guest user to their Azure AD?  I don't know for sure if they've done that.
- one of the comments suggested that my app would need to be a multi-tenant app for it to access resources in another tenant.  I do not want my app to be multi-tenant in the sense of allowing people in other tenants to login to it, but I do want my account to be able to access resources in other tenants that have been shared with me.  I tried changing the app registration for my app to multi-tenant, and that didn't make any difference.
- in the multi-tenant vein, I found this Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/authenticate-multi-tenant), which states "In the code of your multi-tenant app, get the authentication token for other tenants and store them in the auxiliary headers. The user or application must have been invited as a guest to the other tenants."  In my code I am using Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder to sign my account in and get an access token, using the authority for my tenant.  It sounds like my access token is only valid for resources in my tenant - how do I get a token for another tenant in my code?

Thanks very much for any suggestions, be they pointers to docs, code suggestions, etc!